# What happens to the handle of a window when the latter is closed?

Tags: c, winapi

I am storing windows handles into a list according to a set of keywords passed to my [EnumWindowsProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633498(v=vs.85).aspx) that I compare to the window title (result from calling GetWindowsText).

My [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) function is called in a loop several times and my list is created not to add the same element more than once. At this point, if at runtime a user closes one of the windows I currently have in my list I want to be able to traverse the list and eliminate the handles for the closed windows. I don't want to use IsWindowVisible with every handle in the list cause I need to know if the window was closed and this function will return FALSE for a minimized window.

Is there any other way I can know from a window handle whether the window it was pointing to was closed?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

PS: I tried to put hyperlinks to all the functions referenced but I don't have enough reputation. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [IsWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to check whether the handle is valid.

Note that, since a handle can be reused after a window is closed, you should verify that the window still satisfies the initial criteria (re-check its title, class, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am somehow concerned though about the chances of the handle being recycled to a window with the same name. Is that a possibility at all?

Comment: The probability is low, but it *can* happen and it can be a nasty thing to debug if you're not expecting it. To be honest, I'm sure there are many programs out there ignoring such details.